# Map CRM web api lookup to the name field instead of the guid

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

I wanted to know if there is a way to send the record name instead of the record guid when creating a record through CRM Web API,

for example, when filling a lookup field of type account, I'll be writing `"new_account@odata.bind" : "/accounts('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx')"`

Is there a way to send the name like this

`"new_account@data.bind" : "/accounts('Account Name')"` ?

Comment: any followup questions ?

Answer (score 2):

We have to use either record Primary Key GUID or [Alternate key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/define-alternate-keys-reference-records).

The snippet will look like this: `"parentcustomerid_account@odata.bind" : "/accounts(blg_alternatekey='blg12345')"`

[Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dutchcrmandsharepoint/posts/using-alternate-keys-with-the-webapi)